# Android: GetApplication in RecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-context, recyclerview-layout

I would like to inflate a Recyclerview within a onClickListener Method from a Recyclerview.

For that I know that I have to get the Context from the correspoding activity to set the LinearLayoutManager.

**Problem:**
Since I am using a Recyclerview in Fragment to try to create another Recyclerview I do not know how to get the correct context.

**What I tried:**

- **Use FragmentActivity mContext in my constructor to later on try to get the context via "mContext.getApplicationContext()"** *(got the FragmentActivity from another post, used Context mContext beforehand)*

**Issue in the Code:**
I will break down my Code as good as possible:

1. Find the Code from my first Recyclerview from where I try to initialize the LinearLayoutManager

public class deckbuilder_RViewAdapter_Card extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
public deckbuilder_RViewAdapter_Card(FragmentActivity mContext, List<Cards> mData) {
                this.mData = mData;
                this.mContext = mContext;
            }

 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
fab_deckbuilder_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
public void onClick(View view) {

List<Decklist> listCards = new ArrayList<>();
                listCards.add(new Decklist( ... );

LinearLayoutManager layoutManagerCards = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext.getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
                rvList.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerCards);
                deckbuilder_RViewAdapter_List addCardAdapter = new deckbuilder_RViewAdapter_List(mContext, listCards);
                rvList.setAdapter(addCardAdapter);
}
        });


    }

public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView ivCardImage;
        TextView tvCardName;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View introListView) {
            super(introListView);
            fab_deckbuilder_add = introListView.findViewById(R.id.fab_deckbuilder_add);
            fab_deckbuilder_remove = introListView.findViewById(R.id.fab_deckbuilder_remove);
            rvList = introListView.findViewById(R.id.rv_deckbuilder_list);

        }
    }
```

2. Code from the Recyclerview I want to initialize:

   public class deckbuilder_RViewAdapter_List extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

   ```
   private List<Decklist> mDecklist;
   private Context mContext;

   public deckbuilder_RViewAdapter_List (Context mContext, List<Decklist> mDecklist) {
       this.mDecklist = mDecklist;
       this.mContext = mContext;
   }

   @NonNull
   @Override
   public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

       View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_cardview_deckbuilder_list, viewGroup, false);
       return new deckbuilder_RViewAdapter_List.ViewHolder(view);
   }

   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
       viewHolder.ivCard.setImageResource(mDecklist.get(position).getCardImage());
       viewHolder.ivType.setImageResource(mDecklist.get(position).getTypeImage());
       viewHolder.tvName.setText(mDecklist.get(position).getName());
       viewHolder.tvCost.setText(mDecklist.get(position).getCost());
       viewHolder.tvNumber.setText(mDecklist.get(position).getNumber());
   }


   public int getItemCount() {
       return mDecklist.size();
   }

   public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
       ImageView ivCard, ivType;
       TextView tvName, tvCost, tvNumber;

       public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
           super(itemView);
           ivCard = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivDecklistCardImage);
           ivType = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivDecklistTypeImage);
           tvName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDecklistName);
           tvCost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDecklistCost);
           tvNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDecklistNumber);
       }
   }
   ```

**And Lastly please See my Logcat:**

```
2018-11-11 17:46:15.589 21538-21538/com.example.chris.projectartifact E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.chris.projectartifact, PID: 21538
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.chris.projectartifact.b_deckbuilderTap.deckbuilder_RViewAdapter_Card$3.onClick(deckbuilder_RViewAdapter_Card.java:116)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6291)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24931)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

**Requested edits:**

Layout Cardview Decklist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cardView_deckbuilder_list_id"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:cardview= "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    cardview:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    >

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/axe"
            cardview:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/gl_v_db_list"
            cardview:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivDecklistCardImage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:scrollY="-7dp"
            android:src="@drawable/thunder_gods_wrath"
            cardview:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/gl_v_db_list"
            cardview:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivDecklistTypeImage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/introspells"
            cardview:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/gl_v_db_list_secound"
            cardview:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/gl_v_db_list" />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDecklistCost"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            cardview:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/gl_v_db_list_secound"
            android:text="20"
            android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="16sp"
            android:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            cardview:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/gl_v_db_list_third"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDecklistName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            cardview:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/gl_v_db_list_third"
            android:text="Thunder"
            android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="20sp"
            android:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            cardview:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/gl_v_db_list_last"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDecklistNumber"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="x3"
            android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="16sp"
            android:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            cardview:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            cardview:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/gl_v_db_list_last" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/gl_v_db_list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            cardview:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp" />
        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/gl_v_db_list_secound"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            cardview:layout_constraintGuide_begin="40dp" />
        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/gl_v_db_list_third"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            cardview:layout_constraintGuide_begin="55dp" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/gl_v_db_list_last"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            cardview:layout_constraintGuide_end="15dp" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and furthermore please find rv_deckbuilder_list at the end of the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llCarddeck"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:weightSum="6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/gl_v_66"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4.25">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="1dp"
                    android:text="Rarity"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4.25">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="1dp"
                    android:text="Category"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.5"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="1dp"
                android:text="Order"
                android:textColor="#fff"

                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="4.25"
                android:background="@drawable/x_linearlayoutcontainer_blank"
                android:weightSum="4">


                <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnDeckbuilderBasic"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"

                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/y_basic_layout" />

                <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnDeckbuilderCommon"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/y_common_layout" />

                <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnDeckbuilderUncommon"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/y_uncommon_layout" />

                <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnDeckbuilderRare"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2.5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2.5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2.5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/y_rare_layout" />

                <!--<TextView-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/textView"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="0dp"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:layout_weight="1"-->
                <!--android:text="android:layout_weight=&quot;4.25&quot;&#xA;-->
                <!--android:layout_marginStart=&quot;1dp&quot;&#xA;                android:layout_marginEnd=&quot;1dp&quot;" />-->
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="4.25"
                android:background="@drawable/x_linearlayoutcontainer_blank"
                android:weightSum="4"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >
                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerDeckbuilderCategory"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
                    android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="15sp"
                    android:autoSizeMinTextSize="10sp"
                    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                    android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
                    android:popupBackground="#8A8A8A"
                    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerDeckbuilder"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"

                    android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="15sp"
                    android:autoSizeMinTextSize="10sp"
                    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                    android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"

                    android:popupBackground="#8A8A8A"
                    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.5"
                android:background="@drawable/x_linearlayoutcontainer_blank">


                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                        android:id="@+id/switchDeckbuilders"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:checked="false"
                        android:gravity="center|fill_horizontal"
                        android:showText="false" />
                </FrameLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!--<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/rv_deckbuilder_cards"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="0dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="0dp"-->
        <!--/>-->

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_deckbuilder_cards"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/gl_v_66"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/llCarddeck"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llDecklist"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/gl_v_66"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_deckbuilder_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/gl_v_66"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/llDecklist" />


    <!--</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>-->



    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/gl_v_66"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.66"
        android:orientation="vertical" />



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Requested Update 2.0:**

The first RV which is called rvCards (via deckbuilder_RViewAdapter_Cards) is getting inflated in the following fragment:

```
public class deckbuilder_fragment extends Fragment {

//..
List<Cards> listCards;
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    RecyclerView rvCards;
//..

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.deckbuilder_fragment, container, false);
//.. 

//...
dbHelper = new DBHelper(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        dbHelper.createDataBase();
        rvCards = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_deckbuilder_cards);
        updateAdapter();

return view;

}}
```

Whereas the Adapter is updated in:

```
public void updateAdapter() {
        listCards = dbHelper.getDeckbuilderCards(spinnerDeckbuilderType.getSelectedItem().toString(), true, btnDeckbuilderBasic.isChecked(), btnDeckbuilderCommon.isChecked(), btnDeckbuilderUncommon.isChecked(),btnDeckbuilderRare.isChecked(), spinnerDeckbuilderCategory.getSelectedItem().toString());
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManagerCards = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        rvCards.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerCards);
        deckbuilder_RViewAdapter_Card newAdapterCards = new deckbuilder_RViewAdapter_Card(getActivity(), listCards);
        rvCards.setAdapter(newAdapterCards);

    }
```

Comment: It appears that the problem is with "rvList". What is it and where is it given a value?

Comment: @theblitz In my public class Viewholder it is getting initialized.

Comment: @theblitz it is getting initalized as RecyclerView rvList; aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just getting `rvList` from the wrong place, it shouldn't be in your view holder, it should be in your fragment, that's why it's throwing NullPointerException when you click on it.

Firstly, remove `rvList = introListView.findViewById(R.id.rv_deckbuilder_list);` from your view holder, because it will only return null.

Next, update your `deckbuilder_RViewAdapter_List` adapter so it can support data changes:

```
public deckbuilder_RViewAdapter_List (Context mContext, List<Decklist> mDecklist) {
    this.mDecklist = mDecklist;
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

public void setCards(List<Decklist> mDecklist) {
    this.mDecklist = mDecklist;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And also update your `deckbuilder_RViewAdapter_Card` adapter so it can take in a reference of `deckbuilder_RViewAdapter_List`:

```
private deckbuilder_RViewAdapter_List mCardListAdapter;

public deckbuilder_RViewAdapter_Card(FragmentActivity mContext, List<Cards> mData, deckbuilder_RViewAdapter_List mCardListAdapter) {
    this.mData = mData;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mCardListAdapter = mCardListAdapter;
}

public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    fab_deckbuilder_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            List<Decklist> listCards = new ArrayList<>();
            listCards.add(new Decklist( ... );

            mCardListAdapter.setCards(listCards);
        }
    });
}
```

And finally, find the `RecyclerView`s in your fragment, then attach them with appropriate adapters:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // ... after inflate view

    rvCards = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_deckbuilder_cards)
    rvList = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_deckbuilder_list)

    deckbuilder_RViewAdapter_List listAdapter = new deckbuilder_RViewAdapter_List(..)
    deckbuilder_RViewAdapter_Card cardAdapter = new deckbuilder_RViewAdapter_Card(.., listAdapter)
    rvCards.setAdapter(cardAdapter);
    rvList.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hey @Aaron  I implemented your suggestion and I still have to same error. I would like to set the LinearLayoutManager onto a new Recyclerview. I thought the place to use findViewById is in the Viewholder of the first Recyclerview, since I am using a Button in the first Recyclerview to call the new Recyclerview... **But I still have the same error.. Any other suggestions? Can I help you with something?** And anyway, I am new to the concept of a context. Since I thought my View is inside a fragment I need to get the context of the Application. Am I wrong with that?Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: Okay, could you share you layout_cardview_deckbuilder_list, and also the layout that includes rv_deckbuilder_list?

Comment: I did that. Hopefully that is of help @Aaron. :)

Comment: I think I know what you're trying to do.. Firstly you certainly do not need these line `rvList = introListView.findViewById(R.id.rv_deckbuilder_list);` because I don't think it's in the item view. And next, you probably want to pass `rvList` to the adapter.

Comment: @Christian.gruener I've updated my answer, hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. Sorry, I am kind of new.. how to I pass the rvList to the adapter? What I tried was creating `private Recyclerview rvList` in the *class deckbuilder_RViewAdapter_Card*. But since viewHolder.findViewById does not work how should I pass the Recyclerview?

Comment: Where (fragment or activity) do you inflates your view that contains rv_deckbuilder_list? That's where you can find your recycler view, and also where you should set the layout manager and adapter. If you don't mind pasting the code for it maybe I could help.

Comment: I wanted to inflate my secound Recyclerview in the ´OnClickListener´ of the fab_deckbuilder_add. **I updated the code** in  where you can can find where I inflate the first Recyclerview. Since I want to inflate the secound Recyclerview through the first Recyclerview I do not know how to pass the `Recyclerview rvList`.

Comment: @Christian.gruener I'm only seeing one recycler view, when you say you want to inflate a second recycler view I assume it's the same recycler view with id of rv_deckbuilder_list, right?

Comment: So what I want to do is to use a Button (fab_deckbuilder_add) in my already inflated recyclerview which is `rv_deckbuilder_cards` (getting inflated in updateAdapter) to create a new entry(via the List<Deckbuilder>) in the secound Recyclerview which `rv_deckbuilder_cards`. So the issue now is that I do not know how to inflate my rv_deckbuilder_list. I thought I should do that in the OnClickListener of fab_deckbuilder_add but now I realised that have to use a activity to do it. **So what you are saying is that I should inflate rvList/rv_deckbuilder_list in my Activity and just update it?**

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood that earlier, I just realised there's another recycler view in the layout. You can assign the second recycler view in the same fragment, say `RecyclerView rvCards2` for example, and attach a new adapter. And modify your current adapter so it can hold reference to `rvCards2` adapter, so you can update the adapter whenever a card is removed or being added.

Comment: @Christian.gruener Please check my answer again, it should work for you this time!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I would love to give you more points! :)

Comment: Hey Aaron. I know this is not related to the question but I think you understand my setup and can maybe help me with implementing a small change. I would like to `rvList.scrollToPosition(rvList.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1);` (go to the end of the list after adding a new Card to my Recyclerview). Sadly the interaction of the Recyclerview makes this hard. Do you have an idea why I can not use this in the Recyclerview fragment?

Comment: Sure, you could passing in a custom interface for callbacks instead of an adapter to your `deckbuilder_RViewAdapter_Card` constructor. Then have your fragment to implement the interface and simply pass it to your adapter.

Comment: Figured that out by myself! Thank you very much!